# amChart column text rotation automatically

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using amCharts for visualization. Is there any config option in amCharts to rotate automatically the column label text, when is too large to fit horizontally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From version [3.4.3](http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/changelog/) (February 5) `autoRotateCount` and `autoRotateAngle` properties are added to be able to handle this.